# Can any one help me with the title and author of Fantasy novel series with wars between good and evil waged by human champions of various gods

Tags: story-identification, novel

So I remember there being wars between good and evil being waged through wars with humans and some humans being the champion of a god and some being chosen by more then one god. Roughly medieval time with swords and canons and castles. The main character also a protagonist is a champion of a evil god and with great feats gets granted more powers and more from other gods as well to where he is a massive demon (something like 16 feet tall horns and maybe wings).

> at the end he gets killed by a cannon to the head after charging through a castle wall, where he then in his god's afterlife place kills or takes over the previous champion's mountain of skulls or his own mountain of skulls (representing his kill count) is so much larger.

That's about it except it was likely published in or around the 80's before Warhammer came out.

Comment: Any possibility this was a Warhammer Fantasy novel? I can't suggest a specific work, but this sounds a lot like Warhammer's Chaos powers (aka Ruinous Powers). In particular, Khorne, Lord of War, is pretty fond of skulls, although he's not exactly unique in that.

Comment: Unfortunately the book I'm talking about predates Warhammer 40k, that is a very good guess though. But the books I'm referring to do take place with knights and catsles in a medieval era

Comment: My suggestion was Warhammer Fantasy (a quasi-medieval setting, with knights and castles) rather than Warhammer 40K (the later sci-fi spinoff). Warhammer Fantasy was first published in 1983 with the first tie-in novels coming out around 1989. If you know the one you read was before that date, adding that information to the question may help narrow it down.